# How to add pagination in wordpress Static Pages?

Tags: wordpress

Well Guys I'm just asking that How can i add pagination in wordpress Static pages like About US. Actually I'm just add posts in static pages, but its showing just few posts I want all posts, that's why I need a pagination. Please remember I'm just asking about pagination in Static Pages, not in Category.

Comment: How are you querying the posts? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any code in your post. I have done it my own way, check this out.

```
//grab the URL into a string variable (i.e., "yoursite.com/page/2" )
$strURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//array the elements in the string btwn "/" (i.e. [page], [2] )
$arrVals = split("/",$strURL);
//boolean var used to alert when the integer page var is next
$intnextone = 0;
//integer variable for pagenumber
$intpagenum = 0;
// loop through the array
foreach ($arrVals as $value) {
    if ($intnextone == 1){$intpagenum=$value;} // assign var
    if ($value == "page") {$intnextone =1;} //next loop is int
}
```

Thanks.